# Wordpress add_filter makes 500 error

Tags: php, wordpress

Hello i am writing a function to modify the post content and some more information to it. But while doing this it makes the site not to load and throws a 500 Internal server error. Here is my code which i used for the hook.

```
add_filter("the_content","add_related_pics",1);

function add_related_pics($content){
    $pics = "";
    $pics.= '<ul>';
    $tag = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'highlight-tag', true);
    $original_query = $wp_query;
    $wp_query = null;
    $args=array('posts_per_page'=>5, 'tag' => $tag,'orderby' => 'rand');
    $wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( have_posts() ) :
        while (have_posts()) : the_post();
            $pics.= '<li>';
        preg_match('@<img.+src="(.*)".*>@Uims', get_the_content(), $matches);
        $src = $matches[1];
            $pics.='<a href="'.get_permalink().'"><img src="'.$src.'" height="50" width="50"  /></a>';
        $pics.= '</li>';
        endwhile;
    endif;
    $wp_query = null;
    $wp_query = $original_query;
    wp_reset_postdata();
    $pics.='</ul>';
    return $content.$pics;  
}
```

Can anyone point that what is wrong with this code ?

Comment: remove everything and try one function at a time to pinpoint whats the problem. eg. first return only $content and not do anything else, see if it errors, try the wp_query withouth preg_match, etc. etc. smaller steps the better.

Comment: Already did that its getting error with the loop in my script.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the `wp_query` object so thats why you have an error.

Add that to your code and you should be fine.

```
   if ( $wp_query->have_posts()  ) :
    while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) :
    $wp_query->the_post();
        $pics.= '<li>';
    preg_match('@<img.+src="(.*)".*>@Uims', get_the_content(), $matches);
    $src = $matches[1];
        $pics.='<a href="'.get_permalink().'"><img src="'.$src.'" height="50" width="50"  /></a>';
    $pics.= '</li>';
    endwhile;
    endif;
```

and **unless** your going to use `$orignal_query` you dont need to reset the `wp_query` variable to it.

So get rid of your following code in both cases:

```
$original_query = $wp_query;
$wp_query = null;
```